# NARS APL: Rational representation and numerator

Tags: numbers, fractions, apl

In NARS, fractions are represented using `r` example `23r45` will be the fraction 23⁄45. The problem is, if I have a variable that contains a rational number, how do I access the numerator? Does a "numerator" function exist such that `numerator 23r45` returns `23`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in "numerator" function, but you can easily construct one:

```apl
      num←(⊣÷∨)∘1
      num 23r45
23
```

For reference, the denominator can be found with:

```apl
      den←(⊢÷∨)∘1
      den 23r45
45
```

And so you can "split" a rational with:

```apl
      n_d←(,÷∨)∘1
      n_d 23r45
23 45
```